# Better way to dispatch messages to remote server

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance

I looking for a better way to send messages(performance-wise).

I have message loop as follow:

```
 while (true)
 {                    
     if (_outboundMessages.Count == 0)
     {
         Thread.Sleep(100);
         continue;
     }

     var message = _outboundMessages.Dequeue();
     SendMessage(message, _tradeStreamSSL);
  }
```

I have other threads that are adding messages to the message queue at will.
I want to avoid the Thread.Sleep(100), I thought about AutoResetEvent/ManualResetEvent (message loop will wait for signaling form other threads), but there is a good chance for race condition to occur.

Note: important rule to bear in mind, **every message have to be broadcast as fast as possible.**

Any ideas?

Thanks!!

Comment: I don't know when the Messages will come about. It's not a user related thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good use-case for a [BlockingCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/blockingcollection-overview):

```
private BlockingCollection<Message> _outboundMessages;

private void ConsumerThread()
{
    // This will block until new messages are queued
    foreach (var item in _outboundMessages.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        SendMessage(message, _tradeStreamSSL);
    }
}
```